# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in my functions php of Netatmo code

Tags: php

I am using a netatmo php code to show the temperature of my station on my website and since some days ago I see this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   netatmo/inc/functions.inc.php on line 214

Here is what I have on that line:

```
if (isset($res[0]) && isset($res[0]["beg_time"])) {
    $vals = explode( ',' , NETATMO_MODULE_TYPE_MAIN );
    foreach( $res[0]["value"][0] as $key => $value ) {
        $return[$device_id]['m'][$module_id]['results'][ $vals[$key] ] = $value;
    }
    $return[$device_id]['m'][$module_id]['name']    = $module["module_name"];
    $return[$device_id]['m'][$module_id]['time']    = $res[0]["beg_time"];
}
```

I have not touch anything of this file never. Maybe is because my server has upgrade my php version?

This is the res part:

```
                $params = array(
                    "scale"     => "max",
                    "type"      => remove_unknown_values( NETATMO_MODULE_TYPE_MAIN ),
                    "date_end"  => "last",
                    "device_id" => $device_id,
                    "module_id" => $module_id
                );

                $res = $client->api("getmeasure",'GET',$params);
```

Any idea of how can I solve this? The temperature is still appearing correctly but with this warning :S.

Thank you!

Comment: what is this `$res[0]["value"][0]`??

Comment: The error means that `$res[0]["value"][0]` is not an array.

Comment: Any idea how can I solve this so I don't get this error? Edited with the $res part.

Answer (score 0):

A simple patch would be to replace that line :

```
if (isset($res[0]) && isset($res[0]["beg_time"])) {
```

by that one :

```
if (isset($res[0], $res[0]["beg_time"], $res[0]["value"], $res[0]["value"][0])) {
```

But if what you want to do is to retrieve the last measures, I would advise you to use the getstationsdata API method.
You will find the values inside the field

```
devices->0->dashboard_data
```